# How do i obtain the value of an item in a conditional statement?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement

How do I obtain the value of a dictionary item in a conditional statement  for instance

```
names = {"one":"john", "two":"justin"}
prompt = input("enter option: ")
if prompt == names["one"]:
    print("hey, I am here")
```

What will you suggest I go about it with a solution similar to line 3 so that I if the user inputs a key for instance "one" it prints "john"

Comment: I have edited the problem to make it a bit understandable. What I want to achieve is using the key to bring out the value in line 3

Comment: @JUSTINKPAKPA, there are two answers that should solve your problem.

Comment: @JUSTINKPAKPA, you have to accept an aswer if it works, so that others will understand that you already solved your problem.

Comment: As written, your code is checking if the user typed john john, not one. Are you trying to do `print(names.get(prompt))`?

Answer (score 2):

## in

---

In Python exists a keyword called `in`, which is used in several ways.
For example:

```
>>> 'i' in "in"
True
```

## .keys() and .values()

---

The dict built-in class has two methods: `keys()` and `values()`.
They're used like this:

```
>>> Dictionary = {"one":"john", "two":"justin"}
>>> Dictionary.keys()
["one", "two"]
>>> Dictionary.values()
["john", "justin"]
```

And they're also subscriptable, because they returns lists.

## Answer

---

You can do like this:

```
names = {"one":"john", "two":"justin"}
prompt = input("enter name: ")
if prompt in names.values():
    print("Hey, I'm here")
```

## Edit

---

This should work:

```
# According to PEP-8 you should always leave a space after ':' in a dict
names = {"one": "john", "two": "justin"}
prompt = input("enter number: ")
if prompt in names.keys():
        print(f"Hey, {names[prompt]} is here!")
```

Comment: @JUSTINKPAKPA, is there any error raised?

Comment: so what went wrong? You wrote "john" as input and nothing happened?

Comment: Oh, now I understand, wait 1 minute and you'll have your answer

Comment: ok @JUSTINKPAKPA, check my edit, this should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236754/discussion-between-flak-zoso-and-justin-kpakpa).

Answer (score 0):

you could try `in`

```
names = {"one":"john", "two":"justin"}
prompt = input("enter name: ")
if prompt in names.values():
    print("hey, I am here")
```